# Find out if address store in heap or stack

Tags: ida, linux, gdb, stack, heap

While dynamic debugging with ida and gdb-server on binary file running on linux , I saw address that store some value.

How can I know if this address allocated in stack or in heap?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the memory map in the virtual file `/proc/[pid]/maps` (replace [pid] by the process ID of your target).

Usually it mentions memory ranges belonging to heap and stack. E.g.:

```
 address           perms offset  dev   inode       pathname
00400000-00452000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 173521      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
00651000-00652000 r--p 00051000 08:02 173521      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
00652000-00655000 rw-p 00052000 08:02 173521      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
00e03000-00e24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0           [heap]
00e24000-011f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0           [heap]
...
35b1800000-35b1820000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
35b1a1f000-35b1a20000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
35b1a20000-35b1a21000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
35b1a21000-35b1a22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
35b1c00000-35b1dac000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
35b1dac000-35b1fac000 ---p 001ac000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
35b1fac000-35b1fb0000 r--p 001ac000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
35b1fb0000-35b1fb2000 rw-p 001b0000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
...
f2c6ff8c000-7f2c7078c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0    [stack:986]
...
7fffb2c0d000-7fffb2c2e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [stack]
7fffb2d48000-7fffb2d49000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0   [vdso]
```

(from [`man proc`)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Note that addresses may change on every run due to ASLR.